# What's the difference between "flicker" and "twinkle"?

Tags: word-difference

What's the difference between "flicker" and "twinkle"? By dictionary definition, they are almost identical.

Answer (score 7):

They have different connotations.

A 'twinkling' light references images like Christmas lights or other pretty, cheerful things. For example, the poem Twinkle Twinkle Little Star is where many native English speakers hear the word 'twinkle' for the first time.

A 'flickering' light has neutral or negative connotations. A flickering candle can be neutral, but flickering lights are usually spooky, or at least poorly-maintained.

'Flickering' implies that the light has the potential to go out completely, while 'twinkling' does not. This is why stars twinkle, and candles flicker.

Comment: Things that reflect light can twinkle, but usually only actual light sources can flicker. *Twinkling* evokes *sparkling*, *glittering*. Additionally, I would say twinkling is usually rather constant, whereas a flickering light could be sporadically flashing completely on and completely off again.

Comment: +1 Jofsey, both can mean "to to emit light in intermittent gleams or flashes." There are some contexts in which *twinkle* is idiomatic and some in which *flicker* seems more natural. *Flicker* definitely has a broad range of connotation. *Twinkle* can refer to a light source. Stars twinkle. Eyes usually *twinkle*; they don't really *flicker*, I don't think.

Comment: i find this answer bizarre. to me, twinkling implies quickly varying levels of brightness over time, while flickering is blinking completely off and completely on very quickly (perhaps at irregular intervals). two different things. i also don't think "flickering" itself has any negative connotation whatsoever. "flickering *light*" does, but only because lights themselves are so important to us. "flickering" itself is not negative in the least and also does not imply dimming to me. if you wanted to say that, you would say "flickering and dimming".

Answer (score 2):

Both **twinkle** and **flicker** have the meaning of a variation in intensity of emitted light, however they are different

> **twinkling** is a variation caused by **an increase** in light
>   **flickering** is caused by **a decrease** in light

An often used reference is to a **twinkling star** as in the popular [**children's lullaby**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinkle,_Twinkle,_Little_Star). When a star is **not twinkling** it is already observable, and when it twinkles appears to **increase in brightness**.  **Star twinkling** is caused by **the distance of star** from the observer making them appear to be very small sources of light and **atmospheric variations**.  Because planets are closer and larger (as a light/image source) they do not **twinkle**.

Another often used reference is **flickering candle**.  A candle that is lit will have a **constant glow**, variation in light output can be caused by slight air movements causing the candle to **flicker**, in the extreme the candle will **flicker** before **going out**.

> A lit candle **does not twinkle**, and an unlit candle **can not flicker**.

In terms of connotation, **twinkling** has a generally **positive** meaning: **the twinkle in one's eye**.

Comment: I disagree that "flickering" has a negative connotation. Why would so many folks be trying to simulate a flickering fire with electric lights if it were a negative thing? If flicker were negative, why would someone say something like ["When we think of our fireplaces, we envision a welcoming, inviting room where we ...enjoy our holidays with family and friends, and **enjoy a warm, flickering fire**. "](http://www.stoneandmasonryspecialists.com/Fireplace.html)

Comment: **can** have a negative connotation, not necessarily **does**.  Do you mean those wonderful holiday gatherings by the end of which one may want to throw their relatives into the **warm, flickering fire**?  Offending portion has been edited.

Comment: -1 show me a dictionary definition that says what you say about the difference between the two words (flicker is an decrease and twinkle is an increase).

Answer (score 2):

Going strictly by the images that are conjured in my head when I read the two words, it's most often a question of degree.

If I read that a light "flickered", I imagine that it is varying randomly and widely, sometimes almost going out completely.

If I read that a light "twinkled", I picture it varying only slightly and more slowly and regularly.